# laravel Voyager multilingual how to display items with translation in needed locale

Tags: laravel, multilingual, voyager

Does anybody know how to display product's description in current language? I enabled multilingual in **config/Voyager.php** and I have read the doc's but I do not understand ( how to call products from table with translation for example i did like this `$products = Product::withTranslation($locale)->get();` but this not working) clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thx to God!!! I have found answer to my question!!!  Just send locale to view from controller  end write it before using your items 
`if (Voyager::translatable($products)) {
     $products = $products->translate($locale, 'en');
 }`